# How to translate 'make your point?'

Tags: значения

Just interesting, but how would you translate the idea behind 'make my/your point?' Maybe "Я высказался?" (I've had my say.) Or also, when you see what someone is trying to do or convey, maybe with a little bit of frustration and you say, "Alright, you've made your point." Meaning, 'you've expressed what you wanted to express, let's move on.'

Answer (score 6):

There is no exact concept like this, it breaks down into several concepts:

- abstract idea (`высказать свою точку зрения`)
- articulating the point (e.g. `высказаться` this is less abstract without `точка зрения`)
- having heard someone (`выслушать`, `понять`)

In general you can say "everybody can make a point" > "Каждый может высказать точку зрения."

If someone wanted to make a point and says: "At least I made my point." It should translate as

> Но я хотя бы высказался.

If you want to say  "You made your point, let's move on," it will be like

> Хорошо, мы тебя поняли/выслушали. [Но...]

Answer (score 3):

> Maybe "Я высказался?"

Well, maybe *У меня всё*, or *Я всё сказал*, or *Я закончил* etc.

> Alright, you've made your point

Mentor tone: *Хорошо, я тебя услышал*

Aggressive: *Всё сказал?*

Answer (score 2):

"Point" in this context can be translated as "точка зрения" , so one can say

> Ну что же, это твоя точка зрения.

You can also say "высказался", but better as rhetoric question

> Всё, высказался?